How do I assign a result depending on date using sql in access?
I have two tables: The first is a table of roles where each person is in a team but person c has changed teams in June:

The second is a table of signings where it has the name of who signed it and when it was signed.

What I need is some sql that will create a query that will connect the two tables and then show the team name of that person at the time of signing so signing 5 would be when person c was in team x, but signing 6 was when c was in team y. Potentially, but less important would be to also include ability to have Person d who doesn't exist in the role table so would need to show "not found" or blank

OK, but please have in mind, that SO is a forum for code helping, not code writing.

Review https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/10/10/matching-records-using-a-date-range/ - have to build in SQLView and cannot display in DesignView. Alternative is DLookup().

You can use this in SQL View of your query. I changed field names so they do not include spaces or reserved words:
SELECT
    sgn.Signing,
    sgn.PName,
    sgn.DateOfSigning,
    ply.Team
From Signing sgn
Left Join Player ply on sgn.PName = ply.PName
And sgn.DateOfSigning >= ply.StartDate
And sgn.DateOfSigning < ply.EndDate

